# using statement in C# 8 without a variable

Tags: c#, idisposable, c#-8.0

Is there a mechanism for the new c# 8 `using` statement to work without a local variable?

Given `ScopeSomething()` returns a `IDisposable` (or `null`)...

Previously:

```
using (ScopeSomething())
{
    // ...
}
```

However in C# 8 with the using statement, it requires a variable name:

```
using var _ = ScopeSomething();
```

The `_` here is not treated as a discard.

I would have expected this to have worked:

```
using ScopeSomething();
```

Comment: What would be a use case for an object that needs to be initialized and disposed immediately?

Comment: @Saeid that’s not how this feature works

Comment: I wish you could elaborate a little bit more. It is an interesting question but I want to understand why would you not care or interact with a variable for a disposable object.

Comment: @Saeid it’s a common pattern in logging and other areas to provide a sort of context or explicit scope

Comment: Thanks for explaining, if I'm not mistaken, the compiler decides the scope of the "using' statement in C# 8 based on the last usage of the disposable instance. I'm guessing with the pattern you explained, you want to do something (E.g., logging the execution) when the instance is disposed. I think with what you are proposing, the compiler supposed to dispose the instance when the method block ends. I don't think there is a way to do that in C# 8. It can be a good new feature for C# 9!

Comment: @Saeid - "The lifetime of a `using` local will extend to the end of the scope in which it is declared." - That's the current C# 8 implementation. No need to wait for C# 9.

Comment: If you don't have a variable you can't interact with the resource you obtained.  The only thing you could do is have side effects that note starting and stopping.  If you're going to log I would think you want to note success or failure.

Comment: @LorenPechtel its helpful with logging to have some context attributes/variables around the logs. thats where not using the result is helpful.

Comment: In ‘using var _ = ...;’ there is no local being declared. It is a discard. Try accessing it (with ‘_.ToString();’) for example, you will quickly confirm that. Update: I stand corrected. This is a bug. Will file shortly

Comment: Filed https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/43292 . Thanks for finding this issue!

Comment: @JulienCouvreur no problem. i really wish i didnt have to use a discard at all.

Comment: On github: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2235

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two kinds of `resource_acquisition` supported by `using` as per [the specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement): `local_variable_declaration` and `expression`.

I believe the local using in C# 8 is a shortcut to `local_variable_declaration` form not `expression` form as per [the language feature proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using), where you could see:

> **Restrictions around using declaration:**
>
> Must have an initializer for each declarator.

This also provides the ability to use more than one resources in a single using statement as per the language specs states:

> When a `resource_acquisition` takes the form of a `local_variable_declaration`, it is possible to acquire multiple resources of a given type.

So you could do:

```
using IDisposable a = Foo1();
using IDisposable a = Foo1(), b = Foo2(), c = Foo3();
```

It *may* be possible that the language team could add `expression` form support in the future versions, but for now, `expression` is not yet supported.

Comment: +1 This appears to be a valid answer. I just want to point out that with the classic `using` statement, it has always been possible to acquire multiple resources with/without declared variable declarations. For example, `using (Foo1()) using ( Foo2()) { }` was/is supported with the classic `using` statement (assuming `Foo1()` and `Foo2()` return an IDisposable).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Not within the same `using` though, like `using (Foo1(), Foo2())` is invalid, but `using(IDisposable a = Foo1(), b = Foo2())` is valid.

Comment: They compile to the same IL, AFAICT. See [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLTJrAlgY1QGygFtgATKZAHwAEAmARgFgAoagBgAJr6A6ASQDyAbhbUAzF1ocAwhwDeLDkq4TqAFg4BZABQBKeYuVH2WiEQD2CAJ4BlGEmIcoHALwcAdhADupi9bsORHoANIZG4RGRysCuHt6+lrb20EG6IsxRAL4smUA=) vs [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLTJrAlgY1QGygFtgATKZAHwAEAmARgFgAoagZgAI6OBhDgbxYdhXTtQAsHALIAKAJQChI5dQAMHGQDsIAdy70AdAEkA8gakQiAewQBPAMowkxeXKXLhajdr3VDp80sbBydoIld3D34OAF9IuOYYoA).

Comment: Yes because they both valid using statements and translated as per the C# specs.